# jQuery, ajax doesn't fill variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have some problem with jQuery ajax request. when i try to do:

```
$vertices = getVertices();
console.log(getVertices());
```

and my function:

```
function getVertices() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "graph/vertices"
    }).done(function(data) {
        return data;
    });
}
```

I got undefined, and my ask is why do I get undefined ?

Comment: Using Google chrome dev tools,  what is the network pane saying to your request?

Comment: Do you call the function before it is defined? Have you loaded jQuery correctly?

Comment: @Samuel - no, the OP is returning data from an asynchronous function, which can't be done, see the duplicate. Also, the function is called twice in the example above, not that it matters.

Comment: I put function on the top, call ony once andIt's still undefined, respons is properly.